# What means share the feelings of another?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, dictionaries, sentence-meaning

I understand it like having the same feelings (experience the same feelings of another), that's right?
[image]

Comment: Short answer is yes. Long answer is, seeing how you're already using a dictionary to look up the meaning of *empathy*, you can simply use the same dictionary to look up the meaning of *share* (or indeed any word). Alternatively, you can use a bilingual dictionary of your choosing to look up the translation into your mother tongue of either *share* or just of *empathy* proper. Though frankly I'm not sure why you'd need to do that since going by your screen name I have to presume that your mother tongue uses the exact same loanword from Greek shared by a great many languages. **Empatía.**